# How to make UIViewRepresentable focusable on tvOS in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, tvos, apple-tv, uiviewrepresentable

The title says it all - I can't get focus on `UIViewRepresentable` in SwiftUI on tvOS. Any view that conforms to `View` protocol can be focused without problems but neither `UIViewRepresentable` nor `UIViewControllerRepresentable` can.

Any ideas?

This code works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .focusable()
            .onExitCommand {
                print("Menu button pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

This one does not:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewRepresentable()
            .focusable()
            .onExitCommand {
                print("Menu button pressed")
        }
    }
}

struct ViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution ? I have the same problem trying to get a UISearchController working in a SwiftUI app

Comment: @GuyBrooker any updates on this one? have the same issue with `UISearchController`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a UIView subclass that overrides canBecomeFocused to return true. You probably want to also override didUpdateFocus(in:with:) if you want to respond to focus.

For reference here is a utility class I made to let me have focusable UIViews, and respond to remote swipes and clicks.

```
import UIKit

@available (iOS, unavailable)
@available (macCatalyst, unavailable)
class UserInputView: UIView {
    weak var pressDelegate: PressableDelegate?
    weak var touchDelegate: TouchableDelegate?
    var touchStarted: CGFloat = 0
    var lastTouch: CGFloat = 0
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchStarted = touches.first?.location(in: nil).x ?? 0
        lastTouch = touchStarted
        touchDelegate?.touchDown()
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let thisTouch = touches.first?.location(in: nil).x ?? 0
        touchDelegate?.touchMove(amount: Double((thisTouch - lastTouch)/(touches.first?.window?.frame.width ?? 1920)))
        lastTouch = touches.first?.location(in: nil).x ?? 0
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchDelegate?.touchUp()
    }

    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        if isClick(presses) {
            pressDelegate?.press(pressed: true)
        } else {
            superview?.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
        }
    }
    
    override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        if isClick(presses) {
            pressDelegate?.press(pressed: false)
            pressDelegate?.clicked()
        } else {
            superview?.pressesEnded(presses, with: event)
        }
    }
    
    private func isClick(_ presses: Set<UIPress>?) -> Bool {
        return presses?.map({ $0.type }).contains(.select) ?? false
    }
    
    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        pressDelegate?.focus(focused: isFocused)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```